# NUnit tests not running in parallel

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a situation where I want to run tests in parallel using NUnit

To do this I use the attributes below

```
 [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]
 [FixtureLifeCycle(LifeCycle.InstancePerTestCase)]
 [TestFixture] 
 public class MyTestFixture
 {
     [Test]
     public void Test1()
     {

     }
     
     [Test] 
     public void Test2()
     {

     }
  }
}
```

In my actual scenario I have over 200 tests in a fixture

Watching the test explorer in Visual Studio the tests dont appear to be run in parallel

The same applies when running the tests via NUnit Lite

Is there a way of just running this test fixture via the command line to see if its an issue with the runners?

What am I doing wrong?

Paul

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run NUnit tests in parallel, you can use the `Parallelizable` attribute over the test cases.

NUnit 3 offers a [Parallelizable](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/parallelizable.html) attribute, which can be used to denote which tests can be run in parallel

Comment: I have added that and it still doesnt work

Comment: @Paul are you using NUnit3TestAdapter to run tests from Visual Studio? Also, when using nunitlite you need to specify `--workers=NUMBER` to the number of tests you want run in parallel otherwise it will use the same number as the number of processors on the machine.
To just run a specific Fixture from commandline, I believe you can use `--where=EXPRESSION` with NUnitLite

Comment: I have a 4 core processor so is that classed as 1 processor or 4?